# String concatination with PHP constant working on localhost but not on server?

Tags: php, html, echo, web-hosting

I have a index.php where at the top I defined

```
define('ROOT', '/restro/');
```

But at the below code its not echoing expected output

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo ROOT."Restaurant/login.php"; ?>">Login</a>
```

The above written anchor tag pointing to https://foodshalabysid.000webhostapp.com/restro//Restaurant/login.php
instead of
https://foodshalabysid.000webhostapp.com/restro/Restaurant/login.php

But it is working on my localhost properly but not working on ooowebhost server.
where 'foodshalabysid.000webhostapp.com' replaces '/'

please any help

Answer (score 0):

I think you use an absolute path instead of relative.
May be you should use **DIR**:

```php
define('ROOT', __DIR__); // or __FILE__
```

Please look at php doc: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php
I think it will help you a lot.

Comment: after using __DIR__  in place of  '/restro/'  as you said now it points to https://foodshalabysid.000webhostapp.com/storage/ssd3/481/16037481/public_html/Restaurant/login.php  but i want it point to https://foodshalabysid.000webhostapp.com/Restaurant/login.php

Comment: one thing i dont understand why its working on localhost but not on server

Comment: Try to dump $_SERVER and look to your local path https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php